# Low Pass Filters and Bode Plot

Tags: filter, frequency, low-pass

I'm doing some homework for my circuitry class and I'm stuck.

I have to find the value
\$\frac{V_{in}}{V_{out}}\$ of a low pass filter, the schematic of which I have posted below.
[image]

I got the break frequency, which I have shown below, but I do not know how to find the value of \$V_{in}\$ or \$V_{out}\$. I am also confused by what an octave is, but I think it is adding the same frequency per octave.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: * you know the voltage ratio of a 2 resistor divider? substitute the impedance of the cap(Zc=1/ωC)  for R. The calc. method is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

An octave is twice (or half) the frequency away from a given point. Eg an octave higher than 100Hz is 200Hz.

You do not need to know the exact value of \$V_{out}\$ or \$V_{in}\$, just the ratio and the transfer function can determine this.

1. Derive the transfer function.
   This is a simple 1st order filter \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} =  \frac{\omega_o}{s + \omega_o}  \$
2. Determine the "break frequency" a.k.a. cutoff frequency.
   This is straight forward for simple RC low pass filters & you have posted this \$ f_{cuttoff} = \frac{1}{2 \pi R C}\$.
3. determine the frequency of interest.
   This is "two octave's above the cuttoff". Remembering 1 octave is x2.
4. Determine the output ratio at this frequency.
   Using the transfer function from #1. and replacing s with \$j\omega \$ & then determining the magnitude

Comment: So does that mean that two octaves would be (Break Frequency x 3) or would it be (Break frequency + Break Frequency + Break Frequency)?

Comment: it would be break x4.

Comment: So, I've found that the interest frequency is about 23578.508 Khz and the break frequency is 5894.627 Khz.  I can't find what the ratio is though, my book only tells me that the output voltage is 70.7% of the input.  So would it just be 100/70.7?  I really don't know what value I am looking for

Comment: Think about the transfer function. If you replace "s" with "jw"

Comment: ^^^ In other words, turn this circuit into the Laplace domain. This will help you with your bode plot.